# Trying to compare value of meta tag using sitemesh and EL

Tags: jsp, el, sitemesh

I am trying to compare value of meta tag returned by sitemesh with a string but its not displaying correct result. Below is code what I am trying. Please Let me know if something wrong.

```
<c:set var="pageName" scope="request"  ><sitemesh:write property='meta.menu'/></c:set>
<c:if test="${pageName=='Doctorhome'}"> somthing </c:if>
```

This is not printing if block content. Also  I tried to print ${pageName}, it prints **Doctorhome**.

Kindly let me what problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the value attribute of `c:set` tag,

```
<c:set var="pageName" scope="request" value="${<sitemesh:write property='meta.menu'/>}" />
<c:if test="${pageName == 'Doctorhome'}"> somthing </c:if>
```

Comment: Sorry dude, but I think this  way of value assignment is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

"pageName" is in the request scope, so change this line:

```
<c:if test="${pageName=='Doctorhome'}"> somthing </c:if>
```

to

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.pageName=='Doctorhome'}"> somthing </c:if>
```

Also check requestScope.pageName for white space when you dump it to a screen, by prepending and appending a character before and after it:

```
<c:out value="=${requestScope.pageName}="/>
```

And make sure there are no spaces between the equal signs and the DoctorHome text.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. But while printing with <c:out> it prints '<sitemesh:write property='meta.menu'/>'. but if same i print with ${requestScope.pageName} it prints 'Doctorhome'. I am feeling as sitemesh tag is processing after the operation of C tags.

Comment: In sitemesh 2 we had decorator:getproperty tag with that my requirement was working properly. But in sitemesh 3 I am unable to get same funcationality as decorator:getProperty. If anyone have an idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of R&D I observed sitmesh write tag is getting processed after the EL.
So I am using EL itself to check the page value.